# I want to play the slider to slide all 3 slider images and then stop (not loop) in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want it to play all 3 slides and then stop (not loop). When I hit the replay button, I want the slider to start playing at slide 1 again and continue until the last slide.

I have not too much experience in jquery. I have made this but can't stop the slider after 3 slides and also can't fix the replay function.

```
<!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
<!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Collapse Random
        { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }

        //Fade in LR Chess
        , { $Duration: 1200, y: 0.3, $Cols: 2, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true }

        //Rotate VDouble+ out
        , { $Duration: 1000, x: -1, y: 2, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.85 } }

        ////Swing Inside in Stairs
        //, { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Zoom HDouble+ out
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 4, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 11, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }

        ////Dodge Pet Inside in Stairs
        //, { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Rotate Zoom+ out BL
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 4, y: -4, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8 } }

        //Dodge Dance Inside in Random
        , { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.3, y: -0.3, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5 } }

        //Rotate VFork+ out
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: -3, y: 1, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 28 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7 } }

        //Clip and Chess in
        , { $Duration: 1200, y: -1, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Top: [0.5, 0.5], $Clip: [0, 0.5] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $ScaleClip: 0.5 }

        ////Swing Inside in Swirl
        //, { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationSwirl, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }

        ////Rotate Zoom+ out
        //, { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} }

        ////Dodge Pet Inside in ZigZag
        //, { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }

        //Rotate Zoom- out TL
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5 } }

        //Rotate Zoom- in BR
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Top: [0.2, 0.8], $Zoom: [0.2, 0.8], $Rotate: [0.2, 0.8] }, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5 } }

        // Wave out Eagle
        , { $Duration: 1500, y: -0.5, $Delay: 60, $Cols: 24, $SlideOut: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationCircle, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Round: { $Top: 1.5 } }

        //Expand Stairs
        , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2050, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }

        //Fade Clip out H
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 3, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }

        ////Dodge Pet Inside in Random Chess
        //, { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Top: [0.2, 0.8] }, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15, $Row: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        ];

        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html#captiondefinition
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html

        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 1300, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["TR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["L|IB"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R|IB"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T|IB"] = { $Duration: 1200, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 3, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|TB"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 12, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|T"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 4, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["WV|B"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.2, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Left: 1.5} };

        _CaptionTransitions["TORTUOUS|VB"] = { $Duration: 1800, y: -0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["LISTH|R"] = { $Duration: 1500, x: -0.8, $Clip: 1, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic, $ScaleClip: 0.8, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.4, 0.6], $Clip: [0, 0.4], $Opacity: [0.4, 0.6]} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|360"] = { $Duration: 900, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["T|IE*IE"] = { $Duration: 1800, y: 0.8, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1.5, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutElastic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInElastic, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutElastic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Zoom: [0, 0.8], $Opacity: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTTS|R"] = { $Duration: 1300, x: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTTS|T"] = { $Duration: 2400, y: 0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} };

        _CaptionTransitions["DDGDANCE|RB"] = { $Duration: 1800, x: -0.3, y: -0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["DDG|TR"] = { $Duration: 1800, x: -0.3, y: 0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["FLTTR|R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.2, y: -0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };
        _CaptionTransitions["FLTTRWN|LT"] = { $Duration: 1800, x: 0.5, y: 0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.7], $Top: [0.1, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["ATTACK|BR"] = { $Duration: 1500, x: -0.1, y: -0.5, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["FADE"] = { $Duration: 900, $Opacity: 2 };

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
            $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 4,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 980), 300));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>


<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 768px; height: 1280px; overflow: hidden;">
    <embed src="img/Jingle Bells2.mp3" autostart="true" loop="false">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <!-- Slides Container --> 
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 768px; height: 1280px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="img/01.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="CLIP|LR" du="1900" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:60px; top: 40px; width:625px; height:141px;"> 
            <img src="img/santawish_text.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="L|IB" t2=L d=-900 style="position:absolute; left:90px; top: 220px; width:270px; height:270px;"> 
                <img src="img/aarth02.png" />
            </div> 
            <div u=caption t="RTT|360" d=-200 style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 220px; width:270px; height:270px;">
                <img src="img/aarth03.png" />
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="DDGDANCE|RB" t2="RTT|10" d=-1800 du=3800 class="captionOrange" style="position:absolute; left:170px; top: 520px; width:418px; height:418px; text-align: left;">
                <img src="img/aarth01.png" />
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="T|IE*IE" d=-1600 du=3800 t2="B" class="captionOrange" style="position:absolute; left:60px; top: 1040px; width:641px; height:77px;">
                <img src="img/returns_wishes.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="ZMF|10" t2="B" d=-1300 style="position:absolute;left:239px;top:950px;width:261px;height:55px;"><img src="img/aarth.png" alt="" /></div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <img u="image" src="img/04.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="RTTS|T" d=-300 t2="B" class="captionOrange" style="position:absolute; left:70px; top: 30px; width: 618px;height: 84px;"> 
            <img src="img/birthday.png" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d=-600 class="bricon" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class="bricon" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -30px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class="bricon" style="position:absolute; top:150px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -60px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class="bricon" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -90px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class="bricon" style="position:absolute; top:250px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -120px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="LISTH|R" t2="CLIP|TB" d=-600 class=captionOrange style="position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 95px; width: 576px;height: 721px;">
                    <img src="img/bro04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <img u="caption" t="T|IB" t2=B d=-900 src="img/bro01.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:70px;top:920px;width:193px;height:193px;" />
            <img u="caption" t="RTTL|BR" d=-450 src="img/bro02.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:295px;top:920px;width:193px;height:193px;" />
            <img u="caption" t="T|IB" t2=B d=-900 src="img/bro03.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:520px;top:920px;width:193px;height:193px;" />
        </div>

        <div> 
            <img u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />                
            <div u=caption t="T" t2=NO style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top:40px; width:720px; height:400px;padding-top:10px;"> 
                <img src="img/address.png" alt="" />                    
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="DDG|TR" t2="TORTUOUS|VB" d=-750 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:75px; top: 500px; width:575px;"> 
            <img src="img/time.png" alt="" />
            </div>                
            <div u="caption" t="RTTS|R" d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:165px;top:600px;width:414px;height:545px;"><img src="img/aarth04.jpg" /></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Example to add fixed static QR code in slider END -->
    </div> 

    <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <style>

        .jssorb03 div, .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av
        {
            background: url(img/b03.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .jssorb03 div { background-position: -5px -4px; }
        .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -4px; }
        .jssorb03 .av { background-position: -65px -4px; }
        .jssorb03 .dn, .jssorb03 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -4px; }
    </style>
    <!-- bullet navigator container -->
    <div u="navigator" class="jssorb03" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; left: 6px;">
        <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
        <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 21px; HEIGHT: 21px; text-align:center; line-height:21px; color:White; font-size:12px;"><div u="numbertemplate"></div></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <style>

        .jssora20l, .jssora20r, .jssora20ldn, .jssora20rdn
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            background: url(img/a20.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .jssora20l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
        .jssora20r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
        .jssora20l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
        .jssora20r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
        .jssora20ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
        .jssora20rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
    </style>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora20l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora20r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
    </span>

</div> 
<!-- Slider End -->
```

Please help.. Taps

Answer (score 0):

Please set option $AutoPlaySteps to 3, and set $Loop to false.